# convert ISO 8601 to specific format using date.js

Tags: javascript, date

i have a `ISO 8601 time`  in javascript not i want to convert it into `MMM-D mm:ss` using [date.js](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/)
but really no idea how can i accomplish it.

here is the sample date `2014-02-26T05:39:27.885Z` i am getting this from server  and if you convert it , it will appear like `Wed, 26 Feb 2014 11:09:27 +05:30` and i want to show it as `Feb - 26 09:27`

using following i can i achieve this  `Feb - 26 09:27`

```
    var dateTime = Date.today().toString("MMM-d") +" "+ new Date().toString("mm:ss");
```

but this is for today's date i want it to fetch it from `ISO 8601`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming date.js is loaded and you have the time as an ISO-8601 string, first create a `Date` object with `new Date(str)` then call `.toString("MMM - d mm:ss")` on it.

You can see this working in the below snippet.

```js
var dateStr = "2014-02-26T05:39:27.885Z";
var dateObj = new Date(dateStr);

var formattedDate = dateObj.toString("MMM - d mm:ss");

console.log(formattedDate)
// => "Feb - 25 39:27"
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Magne What version of date.js are you using, and what browser? It works fine for me in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/mgpn9tnw/

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a runnable snippet of the working code.

Comment: @JordanRunning Sorry, I was under the impression it was plain javascript (which my response was directed at). I realised now that you were using a specific date library.